# how to insert values to a dictionary from a file

Tags: python, dictionary, file-handling

i need store keys from 1 file and values from another file .Like from 1st file, 1st line of that file is 'a' and 1st line of second file is  20.And the dictionary should be a:20

Comment: Read lines from both files in parallel and construct the dict. open, for, zip are your friends.

Comment: You can try ` paste -d :  1.txt 2.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```py
dictionary = {}
with open("file1.txt") as file1, open("file2.txt") as file2:
    for key, value as zip(file1, file2):
        key = key.strip()
        value = value.strip() # If all the values must be integers, do int(value.strip())
        dictionary[key] = value
```